# UML what will be the classes involved in this use case (realization)

Tags: c#, uml

I have a **board** (tabcontrol ) which have pages ( tabpages ) and each **page** have a **canvas** ( panel ) , in each canvas there are **objects** ( buttons ).

Now the buttons are just representation (visual) of the objects stored in a object list .On import every **object** in **canvas** of each **page** of **board** is imported .

What will be the realization (classes to be set) for this use case .

Which is the right way to do it . A or B (as the only important classes are boundary and object )

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can not shortcut from `InterfaceBoundary` to `object` (mind the convention to have classes have an upper case first letter) as they do not share a relation (according to A).

As a side note. I would not directly relate use case and class. It is better to draw realization from a collaboration and put the classes inside (along with all sort of static/behavioral diagrams).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Class Diagram (structural)**

You can use a class diagram to show the relationship between the classes. If I understand you correctly, it should be something like that:

[image]

**Sequence Diagram (behavioral)**

A sequence diagram shows *instances* at runtime. The class "object" is an "abstract" class, so it can not be instantiated. What you have instead are instances of the class "button".

Answer: I would propose to use option A with lifelines of concrete classes.

Example: Sequence diagram that describes the "Import" use case:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for reply @sergej , I had the same thing in mind but the problem is that i cannot access the entities through functions , as "tabcontrol", "panel" and "tabpage" are all system builtin c# classes and cannot create fucntions "import()",foo() and bar() as in your image
, what should i do to implement this sequence digram through code , so as a work around i proposed the A diagram that had only link with object and boundary and all the builtin classes were eliminated , Please let me know if u have any idea.

Comment: Why can't you access the entities through functions? What are the real types and names of the entities? Are those .NET classes?

Comment: Yes they are , name is tabcontrol1 for board , tabpage for page , panel for canvas and button for buttons

Comment: One of the functions/methods the `TabPage` class has is `Hide()`, right? And there are many more, right?

Comment: Yes it has , are you suggesting me to extend the builtin contructors and methods ?

Comment: No. I am trying to understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to draw a sequence diagram, or do you want to implement something in c#? What does "i cannot access the entities through functions" mean? Maybe you should edit your question and make it clearer.

Comment: Ok. I want to achive the implementation of the sequence diagram in c# , the problem is in your diagram every method has access to entities next to it through methods (which is correct way) , in my case I have been using the .NET control classes (for all the entities ). These control classes do not have any method through which I should build relations and interact with the following up class . Only way they interact is through accessing array[] which holds the next entity type objects . Now how to build the relationships which I would show in my class diagram.

Comment: @phpnet I am sorry, I don't understand your question, can you provide some source code. The question "what should i do to implement this sequence digram through code" is not answerable, as you don't provide a sequence diagram.

Comment: thankyou for your help , I might open an other question as I progress in my work and then I would be able to provide source code and detials more . For the time being I am putting this question at pause . And thanks again for your time and your answers helped me alot